# Same error for all four of my functions. C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 3 arguments

Tags: c++

I am working on a project for class. I have it completed thus far and get no other compiler errors aside from error 2064. The exact error I am getting is below. I have been working at this for a few hours now and I am referring to my book, I've looked at other posts and I am still at a loss. Any help is greatly appreciated.

> > 1>C:\Users\tschw\OneDrive\Desktop\Project 07\Project 07\Project 07.cpp(75,73): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 3 arguments

> > 1>C:\Users\tschw\OneDrive\Desktop\Project 07\Project 07\Project 07.cpp(88,76): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments

> > 1>C:\Users\tschw\OneDrive\Desktop\Project 07\Project 07\Project 07.cpp(107,55): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 5 arguments

> > 1>C:\Users\tschw\OneDrive\Desktop\Project 07\Project 07\Project 07.cpp(124,48): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 4 arguments
> > 1>Done building project "Project 07.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
> > ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

double grossPay(int number, double hours, double pay); // hourly function
double grossPay(int number, double salary); // salary function
double grossPay(int company, int project, int number, double hours, double pay);  // contract function
double grossPay(int institution, int department, double hours, double pay); // intern function


int main() {
    // prompt user for type of employee and give EOF instructions.
    cout << "Enter '1' for hourly. Enter '2' for salaried." << endl;
    cout << "Enter '3' for contracter. Enter '4' for intern." << endl;
    cout << "If result is -1, the input was invalid, please input correct employee hours." << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Terminate input by using <ctrl> z on Windows then press enter." << endl;
    cout << "Terminate input by using <ctrl> z on UNIX / Linux / Mac OS X then press enter." << endl;

    int employeeType{ 0 };

    int employeeNumber{ 0 };
    double grossPay{ 0 };
    double overtimePay{ 0 };

    // salaried
    double employeeSalary{ 0 };

    // hourly
    double hoursWorked{ 0 };
    double payRate{ 0 };

    // contractor
    int companyNum{ 0 };
    int projectNum{ 0 };

    // intern
    int schoolCode{ 0 };
    int departmentCode{ 0 };

    while (cin >> employeeType) {

        switch (employeeType) {
        case 1:
            // HOURLY employee prompts and output
            cout << "Enter employee number: " << endl;
            cin >> employeeNumber;
            cout << "Enter number of hours employee worked: " << endl;
            cin >> hoursWorked;
            cout << "Enter employees pay rate: " << endl;
            cin >> payRate;

            cout << setprecision(2) << fixed;
            cout << "Gross pay of employee including overtime, is $" << grossPay(employeeNumber, hoursWorked, payRate) << endl;
            cout << endl;

            break;

        case 2:
            // SALARIED employee prompts and output
            cout << "Enter employee number: " << endl;
            cin >> employeeNumber;
            cout << "Enter employees salary: " << endl;
            cin >> payRate;

            cout << setprecision(2) << fixed;
            cout << "Gross pay of employee" << employeeNumber << "is $" << grossPay(employeeNumber, payRate) << endl;
            cout << endl;

            break;

        case 3:
            // CONTRACT employee prompts and output
            cout << "Enter company number: " << endl;
            cin >> companyNum;
            cout << "Enter project number: " << endl;
            cin >> projectNum;
            cout << "Enter employee number: " << endl;
            cin >> employeeNumber;
            cout << "Enter number of hours employee worked: " << endl;
            cin >> hoursWorked;
            cout << "Enter employees pay rate: " << endl;
            cin >> payRate;

            cout << setprecision(2) << fixed;
            cout << "Gross pay of contractor is $" << grossPay(companyNum, projectNum, employeeNumber, hoursWorked, payRate) << endl;
            cout << endl;

            break;

        case 4:
            // INTERN prompts and output
            cout << "Enter institution code: " << endl;
            cin >> schoolCode;
            cout << "Enter department code: " << endl;
            cin >> departmentCode;
            cout << "Enter number of hours employee worked: " << endl;
            cin >> hoursWorked;
            cout << "Enter employees pay rate: " << endl;
            cin >> payRate;

            cout << setprecision(2) << fixed;
            cout << "Gross pay of intern $" << grossPay(schoolCode, departmentCode, hoursWorked, payRate) << endl;
            cout << endl;

            break;
        }

        cout << "Enter '1' for hourly. Enter '2' for salaried." << endl;
        cout << "Enter '3' for contracter. Enter '4' for intern." << endl;
        cout << endl;

    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Thank you for using this program. " << endl;

}



// hourly function
double grossPay(int number, double hours, double pay) {
    double hourlyWeek{ 0 };

    while (hours > 0 && hours <= 50.00) {
        if (hours > 40.00) {
            hourlyWeek = ( ( pay * 40.00) + ( hours - 40.00) * (pay *1.50) );
        }

        else {
            hourlyWeek = (hours * pay);
        }
    }

    while (hours > 50.00) {
        hourlyWeek = -1;
    }

    return hourlyWeek;
}

// salary function
double grossPay(int number, double salary) {
    double salaryWeek{ 0 };

    salaryWeek = (salary * 40);

    return salaryWeek;
}


//contractor function
double grossPay(int company, int project, int number, double hours, double pay) {
    double contractWeek{ 0 };

    while (hours > 0 && hours <= 40.00) {
        contractWeek = ((pay * 40.00) + (hours - 40.00) * (pay * 1.50));
    }

        
    while (hours > 40.00) {
        contractWeek = -1;
    }

    return contractWeek;

}

// intern function
double grossPay(int institution, int department, double hours, double pay) {
    double internWeek{ 0 };

    while (hours > 0 && hours <= 20.00) {
        if (hours > 15.00) {
            internWeek = ((pay * 40.00) + (hours - 40.00) * (pay * 1.25));
        }

        else {
            internWeek = (hours * pay);
        }
    }

    while (hours > 20.00) {
        internWeek = -1;
    }

    return internWeek;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a local variable declared as `double grossPay{ 0 };` which shadows the function declarations for `grossPay()`. In other words, since there's a local definition for `grossPay`, the compiler will not use the function definitions. That variable seems to be unused, and removing that line should do the trick.

As a more general tip, it's easier to avoid these kinds of name conflicts with this rule of thumb: Name values with nouns and functions with verbs. In this case, that might involve renaming the functions `grossPay()` to `getGrossPay()` or `calculateGrossPay()`.